# Как нарисовать диаграмму с добавлением данных?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, reactjs, jquery-ui

Нужно реализовать создание диаграммы (в виде сердцебиение), кликнул на нужное место, записал данные (сердцебиение) и точечка с линией проставляется. Посоветуйте библиотеки, демо-версии.
Нашел различные библиотеки, а там без добавление данных.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вам нужна любая библиотека для построения диаграмм, которая позволяет обрабатывать события кликов к точки. далее вы сами в обработчике события пишите функционал для открытия окна ввода данных и так далее. Какого то готового решения для конкретно этой вашей задачи вы не найдете.

Comment: взяли картинку с Highcharts, вот ими и пользуйтесь, библиотека весьма хороша

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот собрал то что смог понять из вопроса на `d3.js`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var store = 'https://www.jsonstore.io/1162c4c76a1b748d0d1218636a9b4cd333c2d6b58f0ecedf344f68d1254e02fa'
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var pts = [], k = 1;

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, width + 1])
    .range([-1, width + 1]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, height + 1])
    .range([-1, height + 1]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks((width + 2) / (height + 2) * 10)
    .tickSize(height)
    .tickPadding(8 - height);

var yAxis = d3.axisRight(y)
    .ticks(10)
    .tickSize(width)
    .tickPadding(8 - width);

var gX = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .call(xAxis);

var gY = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(yAxis);

var g = svg.append("g");

var path = g.append('path')
 .attr('fill', 'transparent')  
 .attr('stroke', 'red');
      
svg.call(zoom);

fetch(store).then(r=>r.json()).then(r=>{
  if (!r.result) return
  pts = r.result
  path.attr('d', 'M' + pts.join('L')); 
  pts.forEach(addPt)
})

svg.on('click', e => {
    let pt = d3.mouse(g.node());
    pts.push(pt);
    pts.sort((p1,p2) => p1[0] - p2[0])
    addPt(pt)
    path.attr('d', 'M' + pts.join('L')); 
    post(pts)
});

function post(points){
    fetch(store, {
      headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(points),
    });
}

function addPt(pt) {
    g.append('circle')
      .attr('cx', pt[0])
      .attr('cy', pt[1])
      .attr('r', 0.001)
      .transition()
      .duration(300)
      .attr('r', 3/k)
}

function zoomed() {
  k = d3.event.transform.k;
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x)));
  gY.call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y)));
  path.attr('stroke-width', 1/d3.event.transform.k)
  g.selectAll('circle').attr('r', 3/d3.event.transform.k)
}
```

```css
.axis line {
  stroke-opacity: 0.3;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
button {
  position:fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="600" height="300"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="post([]);setTimeout(()=>document.location.reload(), 100)">clear</button>
```

PS: чтобы сохранять данные в бд уже нужен сервер или какой-то еще бэкэнд, который будет обрабатывать запросы. В этом примере использован публичный [`https://www.jsonstore.io/`](https://www.jsonstore.io/), тоесть каждый кто будет запукать этот сниппет может изменять эти данные...

Comment: А тут можно словить клик ,  где именно точка поставлена  и записать в бд например?

Comment: @Улан конечно можно, я скоро дополню ответ

Comment: хорошо, жду....

Comment: @Улан я обновил ответ

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а почему у `x` и `y` `.domain` и `.range`  начинаются с **-1**?

Comment: @doox911 чтобы 0 было видно, иначе он будет на границе изобрражения и обреезан

Answer (score 2):

Мне понравилась библиотека Flotr2. 
Достаточно простая в освоении.

[Статья на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/137744/)

Answer (score 1):

Использовать можно любую библиотеку (к примеру: http://pchart.sourceforge.net/). Однако в любом случае придется писать обработку на событие (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Готовое решение думаю Вы не найдете.