# Как сделать масштабирование (позиционирование ) d3 v4-v5?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Есть отличный [пример](https://codepen.io/m1kjay/pen/ZYERgN?editors=0110), но он реализован на **d3 v3**. Что в нём прекрасного? А прекрасное в нём то, что при увеличении круги в точках пересечения не увеличиваются, текст не увеличивается и не уменьшается.

Как мне добиться такого же эффекта в 4, 5 версии **d3**?

Магия тут кроется в методах x и y:

```
var svg = d3.select('#test').append('svg')
  .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).on("zoom", zoom)).on("dblclick.zoom", null);
```

Вычитал, что нужно рассчитывать коэффициент **k**, но не пойму как.

> UPD вот [описание моей проблемы](http://emptypipes.org/2016/07/03/d3-panning-and-zooming/).

Comment: Вы использовали несуществущую метку, ответил бы еще вчера

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, приношу свои извинения. Сам вчера посмотрел и забыл)

Comment: а вам точно нужны шкалы? это очень странный пример, шкала обычно нужна чтобы можно было менять масштаб по осям в разных пропорциях, просто масштабирование можно сделать намного проще

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ну так в этом и цель. Например, есть фигура (квадрат) я хочу её увеличивать/уменьшать, без увеличения элементов управления, как в примере с треугольником.

Comment: `по осям в разных пропорциях` то есть отмасштабировать на 2 по Х и на 4 по Y, например, таким образом сделав из квадрата прямоугольник

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нет в одних. Он как был квадратом, так и останется.

Comment: я по этому и говорю что пример странный, для этого не нужны шкалы, я вечером соберу пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стал полностью повторять пример по ссылке из вопроса.

В случае, когда масштабирование по разным осям на в разных пропорциях не требуется, то масштабирование делается значительно проще, а коэффициент, про который Вы спрашиваете находится в переменной `d3.event.transform.k` если обратиться к ней в обработчике события `zoom`.

Вот пример, обратите внимание на обработчик масштабирования...

```
   .on("zoom", () => {
        circles.attr('r', 9/d3.event.transform.k)
               .attr('stroke-width', 1/d3.event.transform.k)
        path.attr('stroke-width', 2/d3.event.transform.k)
        g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    })
```

```js
let pts = [[50, 50],[125, 200],[200, 50]].map(d => ({x: d[0], y: d[1]}));

let line = d3.line().x(d => d.x).y(d => d.y) 

let svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').style('border', '1px solid')
            .attr('width', 250).attr('height', 250)

let g = svg.append('g')

let path = g.append('path')
            .datum(pts) 
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke', 'red') 
            .attr('stroke-width', 2)
            .attr('d', line)

let circles = g.selectAll('circle')
  .data(pts)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', d => d.x)
  .attr('cy', d => d.y)
  .attr('r', 9)
  .attr('fill', 'transparent')
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1)
  .style('cursor','pointer')
  .call(d3.drag().on('drag', function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
      .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
    path.attr('d', line)
  }).on('start', function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
      .attr('fill', 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)')
      
  }).on('end', function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
      .attr('fill', 'transparent')
  }))

svg.call(d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
    .on("zoom", () => {
        circles.attr('r', 9/d3.event.transform.k)
               .attr('stroke-width', 1/d3.event.transform.k)
        path.attr('stroke-width', 2/d3.event.transform.k)
        g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/987598/188366